# How to give password as parameter for the ssh sql commands

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, ssh, passwords

I'm running this command in the shell script by using the crontab.
How to give the password through this command??

```
ssh username@machine-name mysql -u root dbname < mydata.sql
```

Comment: ssh username@machine-name mysql -u root -pPASSWORD dbname < mydata.sql

Comment: did you mean the ssh password ?